# Invoke-RestMethod In Powershell Authorization Issue (header)

Tags: powershell-4.0

I am trying to do a basic GET with Invoke-RestMethod via PS to our Netbox environment.  I am using my API token from netbox and putting it in an Authorization header, but regardless of how I try it, I get "Authentication credentials were not provided" from Powershell.  I'm at a loss as this works perfectly fine via Postman.

```
$APIKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" (removed)

$Headers = @{}
$Headers.Add("Authorization", "Token $APIKey") 
$Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
$Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json")

$URI = "https://dcim.xxxxxxx.net/api/dcim/devices"

$Test = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URI -Headers $Headers
```

I've had tried formatting the headers many different ways, hardcoding things just to test, but to no avail.

Comment: I tested your code on my device and as I could see in Fiddler, all the headers got transferred correctly.

Authorization: Token XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json

Is there any difference between the headers in PowerShell to the headers in Postman?

Comment: Content-Type can be removed as it's a GET request, which has no request body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out if was a combination of a redirect (301) on the Netbox nginx, and the fact that Postman was adding a trailing "/" to the URI without showing that on the request preview. Nginx was adding the "/" when it received it as a redirection and then stripping the header (As would be expected). I just had to add the trailing "/" and it was fine. (Sigh).